# Comparing HTML with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I was wondering something.
In a IM/chat website I'm making, I have it check the database every 10 seconds or so to see if any new data has come in. And also, when the user posts a new comment, it automatically sends it to the database and adds it to the comment list without reloading. But it loads all the comments each time.

I was wondering if its possible to add an effect to the new comment (such as fading in) without doing that to all the old comments as well.

```
function update(){
    oldhtml = $('#listposts');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "",
            url: "update.php",
            success: function(msg){
                $("#listposts").html(msg);
                $('.comment_date').each(function(){
                    $(this).text('[' + prettyDate($(this).text())+']');
                if(oldhtml == )
                });
            }
        });
}
var intervalID = window.setInterval(update, 10000);
```

That's my update code. Here's my post code:

```
$("#postbutton").click(function () {
    if(!$('#post').val()==""){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "data=" + $("#post").val(),
            url: "post.php",
            success: function(msg){
                $("#listposts").html(msg);
                $('.comment_date').each(function(){
                    $(this).text('[' + prettyDate($(this).text())+']');
                });
            }
        });
        $("#post").val("");
    }
});
```

I'm also using prettyDate, as you can see. But that has nothing to do with this problem.

So as the title states, I was gonna try to save the current html in a variable (oldhtml) and then load the new stuff. Then I would compare the two and just use the new comment to fade in. Am I way out there? Am I missing the point?

Oh and please don't down vote me just cause I missed an obvious solution. I thought you're supposed to use it if I don't explain well, which I think I did.

Comment: Don't ask people not to downvote **you**, nobody's downvoting **you**. Your affirmations may get downvoted... my affirmations may get downvoted... because someone didn't agree with one of us.

Comment: What about, instead of reloading all messages, just grab new ones since a certain time stamp? Then you could fade in just the new stuff.  Might be easier than comparing html, and faster if there are a lot of messages.

Comment: I'm not saying they can't downvote **me**, I'm just saying that the time before they did it in the wrong way. Many people pointed it out too. But thank you. I'm sorry for not understanding. :)

Comment: @MrOBrian THANK YOU. This might work. I was thinking that after a while it might get a little slow. :) Thank you. :) I'll try this out and get back to you.

Comment: Also, checking every 10 seconds could be quite server intensive. Have you looked into Comet? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: @MrOBrian I'm trying to change the mysql query to do it, but had no luck. $_POST['latestdate'] is a new variable that the ajax sends. Heres the code                                            SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Timestamp >='" . substr($_POST['latestdate'],1,strlen($_POST['latestdate']) - 2) . "' ORDER BY PostID DESC

Comment: @transparent sorry, can't help ya there :( I haven't worked with mySQL in many years, and I don't know PHP (I'm a C# developer and work with Oracle).  Check to make sure the query is being built correctly and that the `latestdate` you are sending gets updated each time

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your `success` handler:

```
var $dv = $('<div />').css('display', 'none').html(msg);
$("#listposts").append($dv);
$dv.fadeIn();
```

Of course you can use a `<span>` instead of `<div>` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Blaster's...

```
 $('<div />').html(msg).appendTo('#posts').hide().fadeIn();
```